# SwiftUI TextField on WatchOS Autofill One Time Passcode

Tags: swiftui, textfield, watchos, passcode

I am trying to autofill a TextField in SwiftUI with a one time passcode from Messages. The following code works on iOS, but I am working on a standalone watchOS app and wondering if it can get any better there. Here is the code I have:

```
TextField("Enter 6 digit code", text: $code)
    .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
```

If I get a text message with a one time code while I am inside the text field on the watch, I see a popup allowing me to autofill the code. However, if I am not inside the text field when the message arrives, I do not get any autofill option when I enter the text field. Is this a limitation on watchOS or is there some way I can get the autofill option to appear in that scenario?